# Grabbing all frames of a base64 video in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

If I have the base64 of a video file, is there any way I can grab all the frames in javascript without having to play through the entire video or sending the video back to the server?

I am working on a webpage that takes a video, converts it into ascii-art, and plays it. At first, I thought the best way would be to upload the video to the server, decode and convert it there, and then respond with the converted video; however, since I don't compress the output "video" (actually just a huge blob of text) the response is huge and takes a large amount of time to transfer.

I know I can do something like this if I parse the video on the front-end (not sure if this code is missing some things, but it conveys the general idea):

```
var frames = [];
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = base64Value;

function callback() {
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  frames.push(grabFrameFromCanvasContext(context));
  if (video.currentTime < video.duration) {
    setTimeout(callback, 50);
  }
}

callWhenVideoStartsPlaying(callback);
```

But it takes however long the video is to parse. This makes sense for most cases since the browser would be streaming the video from somewhere, but since the source of the video is base64, is there a better way to do this?